# How do i get the 4.0 simulator option in the scheme for Xcode 4.2?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have followed the instructions here to install the 4.0 simulator (except used the 4.0 dmg file) on Xcode 4.2

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31412/how-can-i-install-iphone-simulator-4-2-on-xcode-4-2

When i open up the simulator, i have options:

Hardware->Version->4.0

So i can open up the 4.0 simulator. 
But problem is that i can't debug my app on the device, because 4.0 doesn't show up in the scheme.
Only 4.3 and 5.0 simulators show up in the scheme.

I also have set "Deployment Target" as 4.0

Does anyone know how to get the older 4.0 simulator to show up in the Xcode scheme?

thanks.

Comment: I tried the same link and got all the schemas..  From 4.0 ..  What is the problem you are facing.. what model of iPhone are you using for debugging..

Comment: the problem i am facing is trying to get the 4.0 simulator working so i can test my app with it .. i can get the 4.0 simulator installed, but i cant debug from xcode .. it doesnt show up in the scheme

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 2):

Click on your target and look under the "Summary" tab. There should be a setting called "Deployment Target". Set that to 4.0 and you should be set.

Comment: sorry edited my question, i already have "Deployment Target" set as 4.0 and base sdk as 5.0